# Difference between 'certified' and 'signed' for PDF

Tags: php, pdf, openssl, sign

I'm developping a script which will sign pdf documents. I use tcpdf and tcpdi. I've .key private key, a passphrase, and a .pem cert. I use the function :

```
$pdf->setSignature($certificate,$pk,$passphrase);
```

When I open my pdf, adobe reader said that my document is **certified** but not **signed**....

Does anybody know why ? And how can I sign instead of certificate ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PDF specifications:

> > A PDF document may contain the following standard types of signatures:
> >
> > *One or more approval signatures. ...
> >
> > *At most one certification signature (PDF 1.5). The signature dictionary of a certification signature shall be the value of a signature field and shall contain a **ByteRange** entry. It may also be referenced from the **DocMDP** entry in the permissions dictionary (see 12.8.4, “Permissions”). The signature dictionary shall contain a signature reference dictionary (see Table 253) that has a **DocMDP** transform method. See 12.8.2.2, “DocMDP” for information on how these signatures shall be created and validated. A signature dictionary for a certification or approval signature may also have a signature reference dictionary with a **FieldMDP** transform method; see 12.8.2.4, “FieldMDP.”
> >
> > *At most two usage rights signatures (PDF 1.5)....

That Adobe calls your PDF certified, therefore, means that it is specially signed, it has a MDP signature.